# Polyhedron with four capping ions

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry

Let's say I have a trigonal prism in my crystal structure and this is further capped by two ions it's called a bicapped trigonal prism. If I have three ions it's called a tricapped trigonal prism. But what about four? I cannot find anything like quadcapped, fourcapped, fourfold capped trigonal prism. How would you name that?

Comment: By then, it would be too ugly to deserve a human-readable name. Nearly all huge polyhedra are like that.

Answer (score 1):

After asking more people who already wrote reports with similar structures and a paper I found on the net the most convincing answer I could find was the term 'tetracapped'.

Source: [10.1002/zaac.201400143](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/zaac.201400143)